# python multiprocessing: unrecognized option '--multiprocessing-fork'

Tags: python, uwsgi

I found this article: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/python-multiprocessing/

As I was experiencing symptoms noted there.

In my python code, I am now doing:

```
def startup():
    with get_context("spawn").Pool(4) as p:
        p.map(_myfunc, work_items)
```

However, when I run my program (in Docker - Debian based) I get:

```
getopt_long() error
/usr/local/bin/uwsgi: unrecognized option '--multiprocessing-fork'
```

I was under the impression that `get_context` is local only to that function; but it seems somehow this function is conflicting with how `uwsgi` wants to work.

Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: What version of python are you on, and what is the output of `import multiprocessing.spawn; print(multiprocessing.spawn.get_executable())` if you run it within your program?

Comment: Same issue here, seems like uwsgi does not support launching subprocess with 'spawn' rather than 'fork'. Any kludge around this ?